# Perl concatenate two numbers into another one?

Tags: perl, integer, concatenation

I don't want to add the numbers, but "concatenate" them and interpret the value as a single number. For example,

```
$var1 = 567;
$var2 = 1111;

#trying to explain what I wanna do with java-style syntax
$var3 = parseInt($var1 CONCAT $var2); 

print $var3; #5671111 and is of type integer
```

How can I go about this? Thanks

Comment: May I suggest a pleasant stroll through `perldoc perlop` as a generally useful read?

Comment: yo haters how you gonna downvote this? I didn't know if normal concatenation would be enough to make it into an int... if every question were responded to with "Read the manual" this site wouldn't exist. Honestly I don't think it's that terrible a question.

Comment: FWIW I didn't downvote. Just suggesting an informative read. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl, an integer is something that looks like an integer. Thus string concatenation can give an integer.

```
my $var3 = $var1 . $var2;
print $var3 * 2, "\n";   # 11342222
```

As such, you could force Perl to store the integer as Java would store an `int` using the following:

```
my $var3 = 0+( $var1 . $var2 );
```

Comment: thanks again, I notice you answer a lot of my perl questions =)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
my $var1 = 567;
my $var2 = 1111;

print $var1 . $var2 . "\n";
```

In `Perl`, `.` mean concatenation.

We can code this too :

```
print "$var1$var2\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know that perl does not have datatypes. For all intents and purposes, there really is no difference between the string `"1234"` and the number `1234` in perl. Perl with seamlessly switch to whatever data type the context demands.

So all you need is string concatenation:

```
my $var3 = "$var1$var2";
```

or

```
my $var3 = $var1 . $var2;
```

With perl, there's always more ways to do it:

```
my $var3 = sprintf "%d%d", $var1, $var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl is smart enough to interpret the concatenation of two integer strings as an integer.

So just use concatenation of strings using dot operator.

```
$bigstring = $string1.$string2;
```

in your case

```
$var3=$var1.$var2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The interesting thing is that you can concatenate to get the number and use the value as parts of *the same expression*:

```
my $a = '123';
my $b = '456';
my $c = "$a$b" * 2;
$c    = ( $a . $b ) * 2;
```